# Compile Error on button click in VBA form

Tags: excel, vba, compiler-errors

I get

> Compile Error: Expected function or variable

when I select a radio button and click ok on my form. The top line of code where the macro title is gets highlighted in yellow.

My form is four radio buttons and an ok button.

I've checked the macro names and option button names

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    If Ties.Radio_OpPlan.Value = True Then
        Run clearties
        
    ElseIf Ties.Radio_Prior.Value = True Then
        Run TieToPrevious
        
    ElseIf Ties.Radio_Custom.Value = True Then
        Run CustomTie
        
    ElseIf Ties.Radio_NetCase.Value = True Then
        Run NetCaseTie
        
    Else
        output = MsgBox("You need to pick a case to tie to", vbExclamation)
        
    End If
    
    Me.Hide
    output = MsgBox("Case tied out", vbOKOnly)

End Sub
```

Comment: What is Ties? You need to probably declare it

Comment: it is the name of the form

Answer (score 5):

Your issue is more than like due to the use of [`Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2003/aa220716(v%3Doffice.11)). This is used to call a macro from its name as a String.

Try removing `Run` from your different methods and see if that fixes it.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If Ties.Radio_OpPlan.Value = True Then
        clearties
    ElseIf Ties.Radio_Prior.Value = True Then
        TieToPrevious
    ElseIf Ties.Radio_Custom.Value = True Then
        CustomTie
    ElseIf Ties.Radio_NetCase.Value = True Then
        NetCaseTie
    Else
        output = MsgBox("You need to pick a case to tie to", vbExclamation)
    End If

    Me.Hide
    output = MsgBox("Case tied out", vbOKOnly)
End Sub
```

---

#### Additional Notes

- [Try not to use underscore case](https://github.com/todar/VBA-Style-Guide#underscore--case). Underscores have special meanings in VBA for events and implementations. So instead of `Radio_OpPlan` you could do `RadioOpPlan`, or even better simply `OpPlan` (really even make `OpPlan` even more descriptive).
- In my opinion, a `Case` statement looks cleaner in this situation.

```
Select Case True
    Case RadioOpPlan
        clearties
    Case RadioPrior
        TieToPrevious
    Case RadioCustom
        CustomTie
    Case RadioNetCase
        NetCaseTie
    Case Else
        output = MsgBox("You need to pick a case to tie to", vbExclamation)
End Select
```

Comment: `If Ties.Radio_OpPlan.Value = True Then` is simply `If Ties.Radio_OpPlan.Value Then`; similar for the other statements.

Comment: @ajd I'm not sure what you are trying to comment on? =)

Comment: Robert: the coding anti-pattern `If x=True Then`. A simple `If x Then` suffices. Might seem trivial, but that line of thought leads to other anti-patterns that produce 5 lines of code when a simple assignment suffices.

Comment: @ajd hence why I put in my additional notes an example of how I would suggest going about it (to a certain extent). The first example is simply to show how to remove the error.

Comment: @ErinWilliams did this answer your question? Or is it still giving you the same error?

Answer (score 0):

this is what worked, and all the macros had to make sure they started with selecting the sheet I was making changes on first

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()


If Ties.OpPlan.Value = True Then
clearties
ElseIf Ties.Prior.Value = True Then
TieToPrevious
ElseIf Ties.Custom.Value = True Then
CustomTie
ElseIf Ties.NetCase.Value = True Then
NetCaseTie
Else
output = MsgBox("You need to pick a case to tie to", vbOKOnly)
End If


Me.Hide


End Sub
```

Comment: this looks similar to my answer to you. If you found my answer was correct you can mark it accepted. Reposting the same answer might confuse future readers.

Comment: If you selected a sheet you probably did it wrong. You might benefit from reading 
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba). Using `.Select` is a very bad practice and in 99.9 % of the cases it is not necessary to select a sheet.